# JQuery reference to data within an unknown field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The data being provided to me is in the following format:

```
{
"data": {
    "2021-12-13": [
      {
          "constituents": [Data]
```

The problem is that date field for referencing.

Right now I'm going result['data']['2021-12-13'][0]['constituents'];

But obviously when 12-14 comes along, I don't want to hard-code a date in there. Two questions:

1. how can I reference constituents without explicitly stating that date and
2. if they do a 2021-12-14 in the current format, leaving in 2021-12-13, how can I both sort them and get the most recent?

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of the object keys. Then use those to dynamically access the properties. You can also loop over all the properties, using JavaScript `Object.values()` or jQuery `$.each()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```js
const data = {
    '2021-12-13': 'a',
    '2021-12-14': 'b',
    '2025-12-14': 'c',
    '1995-12-13': 'd'
}

const sortedKeys = Object.entries(data).sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => new Date(keyB) - new Date(keyA))
// Now we got an array of object entries sorted by descending date.
// So let's just get the first item and we all good.
console.log(sortedKeys[0]) // Prints [2025-12-14, 'c']
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you!

Comment: No problem! Please mark my answer as solution